# Differentiation under integral sign - problem while finding the constant c

Tags: integration, derivatives, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

Evaluate:
$$\phi(y) = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1+y\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} dx $$

After applying the Leibniz formula, the indefinite integral of $d\phi(y)$ comes out to be:
$$\int d\phi(y)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int dy$$
i.e.

$$\phi(y) = \frac{\pi}{2}y+c$$

Now I am stuck in finding the value of $c$. On putting $y=0$ the integral does not converges! How can I find the complete function? Is it possible or am I doing something wrong. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Indeed, when $y = 0$, 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} csc^2(x)dx = -cot(x)|_{x=0}^{\pi/2} = -\infty.$$
It turns out that for any $y$, $\phi(y)= - \infty.$. 
Since your integral never converged to begin with, the problem as it stands is ill posed. Are you sure there's not a typo?

Comment: $$\frac{1+y \sin^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = y + \csc^2 x,$$ so I don't know why you even need to use differentiation under the integral.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed $\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc^2 (x)\,dx$ is certainly $+\infty$, not $-\infty$, and so is $\phi(y)$.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.